# Operators overloading in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I recently found out about overloading operators in c++. 
When you want to overload a operator in class , and we want to create new object with it , that is made from others we defined we can do

```
NameOfClass operator+(const NameOfClass& b){
  {
         NameOfClass tmp;
         tmp.length = this->length + b.length;
         tmp.breadth = this->breadth + b.breadth;
         tmp.height = this->height + b.height;
         return  tmp;

}
```

I cant figure out if i define 2 objects before this. e.g

```
NameOfClass one(length,breadth,height);
NameOfClass two(length,breadth,height);
```

I set their attributes.
but how does

```
NameOfClass three=one+two;
```

set the attributes of "three"? Are both one and two considered as argument to "+" overloaded operator. The function clearly says

```
tmp.length = this->length + b.length;
```

but this-> length should be undefined and b.length is private. How does it mix it together?
Or is it taken as method so `one+two` = the + is method of one and two is being passed as argument , meaning that this->length  reffers to to length of "one" object?
Using example from tutorialspoint.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Box
{
   public:

      double getVolume(void)
      {
         return length * breadth * height;
      }
      void setLength( double len )
      {
          length = len;
      }

      void setBreadth( double bre )
      {
          breadth = bre;
      }

      void setHeight( double hei )
      {
          height = hei;
      }
      // Overload + operator to add two Box objects.
      Box operator+(const Box& b)
      {
         Box box;
         box.length = this->length + b.length;
         box.breadth = this->breadth + b.breadth;
         box.height = this->height + b.height;
         return box;
      }
   private:
      double length;      // Length of a box
      double breadth;     // Breadth of a box
      double height;      // Height of a box
};
// Main function for the program
int main( )
{
   Box Box1;                // Declare Box1 of type Box
   Box Box2;                // Declare Box2 of type Box
   Box Box3;                // Declare Box3 of type Box
   double volume = 0.0;     // Store the volume of a box here

   // box 1 specification
   Box1.setLength(6.0); 
   Box1.setBreadth(7.0); 
   Box1.setHeight(5.0);

   // box 2 specification
   Box2.setLength(12.0); 
   Box2.setBreadth(13.0); 
   Box2.setHeight(10.0);

   // volume of box 1
   volume = Box1.getVolume();
   cout << "Volume of Box1 : " << volume <<endl;

   // volume of box 2
   volume = Box2.getVolume();
   cout << "Volume of Box2 : " << volume <<endl;

   // Add two object as follows:
   Box3 = Box1 + Box2;

   // volume of box 3
   volume = Box3.getVolume();
   cout << "Volume of Box3 : " << volume <<endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your suspicion that "the + is method of one and two is being passed as argument" is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1.
>
> how does
>
> ```
> NameOfClass three=one+two;
> ```
>
> set the attributes of "three"?

`NameOfClass three=one+two;` will be interpreted as `NameOfClass three = one.operator+(two);`, and `three` will be copy/move constructed from the return value of `NameOfClass::operator=()`.

> 2.
>
> ```
> tmp.length = this->length + b.length;
> ```
>
> but this-> length should be undefined and b.length is private. How
>   does it mix it together?

What do you mean "this-> length should be undefined"? Here `this` == `&one` and `b` == `two`.

`b.length` is `private` doesn't matter because `operator+` is the member function, it *could* access the private member.

Answer (score 2):

`NameOfClass three = one + two;` will use a *compiler-generated* copy constructor in order to construct `three` from the *anonymous temporary* `one + two`. `one + two` is syntactic sugar for `one.operator+(two)` which you have implemented.

Smarter compilers may well use a *compiler-generated move* constructor since it's clear that the *anonymous temporary* can't be used by anything else.

You can implement those constructors yourself, or rely on the compiler generating one which copies (or *moves*) the member data.